# Access local Kubernetes cluster running in Virtualbox

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, kubeadm

I have configured a Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, by creating 3 Virtualbox nodes, each node running CentOS (master, node1, node2). Each virtualbox virtual machine is configured using 'Bridge' networking.
As a result, I have the following setup:

1. Master node 'master.k8s' running at 192.168.19.87 (virtualbox)
2. Worker node 1 'node1.k8s' running at 192.168.19.88 (virtualbox)
3. Worker node 2 'node2.k8s' running at 192.168.19.89 (virtualbox

Now I would like to access services running in the cluster from my local machine (the physical machine where the virtualbox nodes are running).

Running `kubectl cluster-info` I see the following output:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.19.87:6443
KubeDNS is running at ...
```

As an example, let's say I deploy the dashboard inside my cluster, how do I open the dashboard UI using a browser running on my physical machine?

Comment: Are you able to ssh into any of the nodes from your host machine? I think the setup would be relatively the same for accessing the cluster, so you may want to look into it. I think you'd need to ensure port 6443 is forwarded to the host machine so you can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way is to use `kubectl proxy` or a `Load Balancer`, but since you are in a **development machine** a `NodePort` can be used to publish the applications, as a Load balancer is not available in VirtualBox.

The following example deploys 3 replicas of an echo server running nginx and publishes the http port using a `NodePort`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-echo
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.8          
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service-np
  labels:
    name: nginx-service-np
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8082        # Cluster IP http://10.109.199.234:8082
      targetPort: 8080  # Application port
      nodePort: 30000   # Example (EXTERNAL-IP VirtualBox IPs) http://192.168.50.11:30000/ http://192.168.50.12:30000/ http://192.168.50.13:30000/
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

You can access the servers using any of the VirtualBox IPs, like 
 http://192.168.50.11:30000 or  http://192.168.50.12:30000 or  http://192.168.50.13:30000

See a full example at [Building a Kubernetes Cluster with Vagrant and Ansible (without Minikube)](https://www.itwonderlab.com/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way of getting access to the kubernetes dashboard is [documented in their readme](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#getting-started) and is to use `kubectl proxy`.

One should not have to ssh into the cluster to access any kubernetes service, since that would defeat the purpose of having a cluster, and would **absolutely** shoot a hole in the cluster's security model. Any ssh to `Nodes` should be reserved for "in case of emergency, break glass" situations.

More generally speaking, a well configured [Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/nginx-0.12.0#readme) will surface services en-masse and also has the very pleasing side-effect of meaning your local cluster will operate exactly the same as your "for real" cluster, without any underhanded ssh-ery rules required

Comment: I guess this needs 'kubectl proxy' to run on the host (physical machine hosting the three virtual machines). Unfortunately at the moment I can run kubectl from inside the VM that is running the master node.

Comment: Yes, it does, but if you are playing with kubernetes, you are 100% going to want to have a working `kubectl` otherwise, wow, it will be painful to have to scp all the yaml (et al) into the vm, apply them with kubectl, repeat